# How to show data for Launches, Environment, Trend and Executors in Allure Report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, allure

I am using allure 2.1.1. Allure Report is only showing executed test in Overview tab. How to show data for Launches, Environment, Trend and Executors.

[image: Current screen]

Answer (score 6):

I am looking for this answers too.
I found only how to show data for Environments [allure wiki](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/wiki/Environment)

Also I understood how to setup Trend graphics. After report generation, you should copy `...\allure-report\history` folder to `...\allure-results` folder. Then when you make report from allure-results it will generate report with history trend graphics.

Comment: Also you can use one of Allure CI plugins (Jenkins/TeamCity/Bamboo) to get history features

Answer (score 1):

For Environment to be displayed you have to create a xml file with the name as **environment.xml** and store it in your allure-result folder. you can  look into this url https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_environment . Your xml file should be following syntax

```
<environment><parameter><key>Browser</key><value>Chrome</value></parameter></environment>
```

For Executor to be displayed you have to create a json file with name as **executor.json** and store it in your allure-result folder, for displaying executor you can view my answer in [Executor is not displayed in Allure reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60902458/executor-is-not-displayed-in-allure-reports)

For trends and other graphs to be displayed, follow the following steps

1. run you test cases, allure-results folder with json files and screenshots is created
2. open cmd prompt
3. run following cmd in cmd prompt

   ```
    allure generate path_of_allure-report_folder_generated --clean -o allure-report
   ```
4. Now copy the history folder from the allure-report folder which is generated in the allure-result folder.
5. Open cmd prompt and navigate to the project folder where the allure-result folder is present and run below command

   ```
    allure serve
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is just to copy (and replace) content of the history folder

from: allure-report/history/
to: allure-results/history/