# Executor is not displayed in Allure reports

Tags: java, testng, allure

Executor is not getting displayed in Allure reports. I have created a **executor.json** file which has only 1 attribute i.e., tester as we can see the code below

**executor.json**

```
{"Tester":"Suhail"}
```

when I generate the report I am not getting Executor field it is showing as **Unknow** as you can see the screenshot attached below

[image]

I am using Allure version-2.13.2

can anyone help me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 3):

I was going through this and found out interesting so posting it as an answer,if anyone has more details on this please paste your answer.

So here is my findings,

in executor.json file, we need to have general syntax like below

```
{"name":"Suhail", // this will print the tester name on the report
"buildName":"Give the project Name", // if this attribute is not given that **Unknown** is displayed
"type":"jenkins" // if this attribute is not given we will be getting a user icon next to the name else a hat icon will be  displayed
}
```

I could find only this much, if anyone know how to enter more records of executors then please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

As you already found out the Executor is display if you have a **executor.json** file in your **allure-results** folder when you generate your report.

This file is usually generated by your builder, for example Jenkins with the plugin allure.

If you want to manually add theses informations here what the file look like:
[executor.json](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-demo/blob/master/allure-results/executor.json)

```
{
  "name": "Jenkins",
  "type": "jenkins",
  "url": "http://example.org",
  "buildOrder": 13,
  "buildName": "allure-report_deploy#13",
  "buildUrl": "http://example.org/build#13",
  "reportUrl": "http://example.org/build#13/AllureReport",
  "reportName": "Demo allure report"
}
```